# Transform the conditional sentence beginning with word 'Unless'

Tags: sentence, conditionals, unless

I have a sentence and need to transform it to begin with word *unless*.

The sentence is **Study hard now or you will regret it later.**  I am not able to begin this using *Unless.*

My attempts are

> - Unless you don't study hard, you will regret it
> - Unless you don't study hard now, you won't cherish it.

I guess both of my attempts are incorrect: how do I get it right?

Comment: Please add your definition of "unless" so that we can see the problem you're having.

Comment: its the dictionary definition only. What else would i use?

Comment: I mean, please edit your question to include the definition. I can't tell what you think the word *unless* means if you don't tell me. Then we can see what the problem is. (You're supposed to do this - show your work - on this site anyway.

Comment: @medica I'd agree with your point about any kind of lexical word, but not with grammatical words like *if* or *unless*. People have been arguing about the meaning of *if* for at least two and a half milenia, and they haven't got anywhere yet! ;) Have you got a definition for *if* or *unless*? If you have, do you want to write my PhD for me? I'll pay you handsomely!

Comment: This question belongs on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). And the answer is *Unless you study hard now...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Or* used in this way has a conditional meaning very different to its normal logical meaning. If the sentence is paraphrased as *A or B*, where A and B stand for finite clauses, then it will have the same meaning as *Unless A, B*:

- He'll do it now, or he'll regret it for ever.
- Unless he does it now, hell regret it for ever.

Notice that here we need to use a present tense in the *unless* clause, because temporal and conditional subordinate clauses resist the use of *will* to express futurity.

Where A is an imperative, as in the Original Poster's example, the missing subject, *you*, needs to be re-inserted. Actual imperatives can't be used in conditional antecedents (that means in the subordinate clause).  We need a proper finite clause with a tensed verb.

In the Original Poster's particular example:

> Unless you study hard now, you will regret it later.

*Hope this is helpful!*